# Converting String to Float

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am attempting to parse a string into an array, take a section of the array at index 1 and convert that string into a float. I have my code here but I am getting the error "Intializing 'float' with an expression of incompatible type 'NSString *_strong'. Help!

```
NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"]];

NSArray *array = [csv componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *price = [array objectAtIndex:1];

[price floatValue];

float currentPrice = price;
```

Comment: As per the documentation [floatValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/floatValue) returns float value corresponding the string objects passed. It doesn't convert a string into a float. What you have tried is by assuming that `[price floatValue];` converts param `price` into a float and thus you can assign to `currentPrice` which is not the way it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
float currentPrice = [price floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
float currentPrice = [price floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_float = [your_string floatValue];
```

try this:

```
NSLog(@"float value is: %f", your_float);
```